# Magento 2 send email very very slow

Tags: magento2, email

When ever I send an email to the customer from the backend, for instance "Send Email" button from orders or from invoices, everywhere it behaves the same. When I click the button, it waits and waits and waits, just like when a page takes very long time to load, and after a minute it is done ok. I've checked the emails and they have all arrived, but the behaviour gives me a very bad feeling.

Answer (score 0):

This it was not Magento fault, but my bad web server configuration Smiley Wink I tried to manually send the mail from CLI of webserver like so:

```
echo "Subject:test" |sendmail mymail@gmail.com
```

and it was waiting a whole minute before the command completed it self and actually sent the mail, so I checked the logs in /var/log/mail.log and saw this:

```
unable to qualify my own domain name (websrv4) -- using short name
```

so I went and edit the /etc/hosts file from this:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      websrv4
```

to look like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain
127.0.1.1       websrv4.localdomain websrv4
```

And the emails are now send instantly. Hope this helps someone else Smiley Wink